# Why am I receiving this Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

I am passing the index as a unique key, yet I am still receiving this warning:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `SectionPackages`

Can anyone guide me on what could be the problem?

```
const SectionPackages = props => {

  const listingPackages =
    publicData && publicData.packages && publicData.packages.length
      ? [defaultPackage, ...publicData.packages]
      : [];

  useEffect(() => {
    listingPackages.map((l, index) => {
      hidden[index] = true;
      setHidden([...hidden]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={listingPackages.length ? rootClassName : css.noPackages}>
      {listingPackages.length > 0 && (
        <h2 className={css.packagesMainTitle}>
          <FormattedMessage id="SectionPackages.title" />
        </h2>
      )}

      {listingPackages.map((listingPackage, index) => {
        const moneyPrice = new Money(
          listingPackage.price.amount * 100,
          listingPackage.price.currency
        );

        return (
          <a onClick={e => handleBtnClick(e, index)} key={index}>
            <div
              key={index}
              className={
                selectedPackage === index && selectedPackage !== null
                  ? classNames(css.packagesContainer, css.packagesSelectedContainer)
                  : css.packagesContainer
              }
            >

              <div className={css.packagesDescriptionHolder}>
                {listingPackage.description != null && (
                  <p
                    className={
                      hidden[index] === true
                        ? classNames(css.packagesDescriptionHidden, 'packagesDescription')
                        : classNames(css.packagesDescriptionShown, 'packagesDescription')
                    }
                  >
                    {listingPackage.description}
                  </p>
                )}
                {elHeight[index] && elHeight[index].index === index && elHeight[index].height > 40 && (
                  <p
                    className={css.packagesDescriptionMore}
                    onClick={e => showHideDescription(e, index)}
                  >
                    {hidden[index] === true ? (
                      <FormattedMessage id="SectionPackages.showMore" />
                    ) : (
                      <FormattedMessage id="SectionPackages.showLess" />
                    )}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't see any immediate issue with this code, the React key use is the mapped array index so it can't be duplicate. Are you mapping anything anywhere else within this React component sub-tree? Can you add the full error message and stacktrace (if available) to your question?

Comment: @DrewReese Added, please have a look

Comment: Thanks, it's still not clear exactly where a duplicate key is possible. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox with mock data/props for this component that reproduces the key issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use map or any other looping function you need to assign a unique key to each element you generate in react.

In your case you are assigning the index to the "a" tag and the "div" within the same loop.

You can make them unique by adding some kind of prefix maybe something like:

```
     <a onClick={e => handleBtnClick(e, index)} key={`a_${index}`}>
        <div
          key={`div_${index}`}
```

that way the key for the a is different than the key for the div.

As an alternate solution you could remove the "key" from the div and leave it on the "a" tag.

**NOTES**
I want to clarify because there seem to be some confusion about how this works.

In this case the **same key** is being used both for the **"a" and the "div"** which are both within the **same loop**.

You need to assign the key to the root element being returned by the map function in this case **"a"**.

React will use the key to compare previous virtual dom with current virtual dom and perform merges.  This has nothing to do with "identifying" elements within elements.

Also it is not recommeded to use "index" as key because the index might end up on a different item on the next pass.

This is a quote from react's documentation:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Also check [Index As Key Anti-Pattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: This is a great comment. Not so great an answer since it really just states the obvious. Also, keys need only be unique among siblings, not children, so the nested `div` can use the same React key.

Comment: @DrewReese not really I dont agree with you. It is not obvious that he is using the same key for two different objects within the same loop. Also it is the correct answer in this case.

Comment: The array index will ***always*** be unique for all elements, by definition. There's no possible way to have duplicate indices in an array. You don't have to agree with me, but this answer is incorrect. Here's a refresher on [React keys and usage](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), pay ***close*** attention to the second section regarding ***uniqueness among siblings***.

Comment: But I have assigned unique key to the parent ```<a>```, can you please break down what you are saying?

Comment: it is not unique because you assigned the same key to both the "a" and the "div".... the requirement is not "within a parent" is within the "parent of the elements in the loop".  @LaveenRen

Comment: @LaveenRen in other words you need to make the div key different or remove it.  The one key requried is the "a" tag key which is the root element returned by the map function.

Comment: @DrewReese you are wrong in the sense that you can still end up assigning the same key to two different elements within the same loop like it happened in this case.  It is actually NOT recommended to use "index" as key.

Comment: I believe the confusion is on your part. Any React key of a child component of the mapped component is completely irrelevant and isn't the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese there is a very simple experiment just remove the second key and see what happens

Comment: You're absolutely correct, it ***is*** a very trivial [experiment](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-am-i-receiving-this-warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-m7r48). I'll wait for you to process the result and revise your stance.

Comment: @DrewReese even though I do agree with you in how the children key works. It seems that under certain circumstances what I have said here is also true.